# Backbone: Is it possible to have multiple fetches at once

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im trying to call multiple `fetch()` at once, currently when I run this:

```
function notWorking(){
    collection1.fetch()
    collection2.fetch()
    collection3.fetch()
    collection4.fetch()
}
```

If I only `fetch()` one and returns a 500 internal error on the other 3 `fetch()`
but, if i run this:

```
function working(){
    collection1.fetch({
       success:function(){
            collection2.fetch({
               success:function(){
                    collection3.fetch({
                       success:function(){
                            collection4.fetch()
                       }
                    })
               }
            })
       }
    })
}
```

Works but seem like its horrible practice, is it a better way to pull multiple `fetch()` at one time?

(the backend is is using ruby with sinatra and datamapper for whats its worth)

Comment: It's definitely possible. `fetch()` calls are asynchronous, so the failures are not due to Backbone. The `500` error code means that it's a server-side error - check your Sinatra code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your core problem is a server-side one, as voithos suggested.  There is nothing in Backbone (or even in jQuery) that would prevent you from making multiple fetches at once.

That being said, if you're stuck with your server-side implementation, you can at least clean up your code a bit, by taking advantage of the fact that Backbone's fetch returns jQuery's ajax return result (which is itself a "Deferred" object):

```
function working(){
    collection4.fetch().complete(
        collection3.fetch().complete(
            collection2.fetch().complete(
                collection.fetch()));
}
```

Alternatively you can actually make AJAX requests synchronous, by passing the appropriate option to jQuery through fetch, like so:

```
function working(){
    collection.fetch({async: false});
    collection2.fetch({async: false});
    collection3.fetch({async: false});
    collection4.fetch({async: false});
}
```